# Annihilation cross-section of neutrino-antineutrino pairs

Tags: neutrinos, weak-interaction, chirality

Presumably this should be a tiny cross-section (or not?), but presumably it should be at least qualitatively similar to the 511 keV line that clearly distinguishes electron-positron annihilation, although by the upper mass bounds on the different types of neutrinos, such line should be presumably be somewhere in the microwave region or below. Even if the rate is tiny, it could be detectable cosmologically, if we knew in what region of spectra to look

On the other hand, considering that the inverse process (photon to neutrino-antineutrino pair $\gamma \gamma \rightarrow \nu \bar{\nu} $) could only be experimentally tested with left-handed $\nu$, right-handed $\bar{\nu}$ pairs, we should expect to see at least half the rate since *theoretically* the pair production channel toward **right-handed**-neutrino-**left-handed**-antineutrino pairs should not be suppressed in this case, correct? and at least from our galactic frame of references, those chiralities should behave as sterile neutrinos

Comment: Neutrinos are neutral.

Comment: @CosmasZachos does that mean that neutrinos and antineutrinos will not annihilate? or that the rate of decay into photons is absolute zero?

Comment: The neutrinos "can" annihilate to a (virtual) *Z*, and there is an anomalous coupling of that to γγ, not realistic. Estimate.

Comment: @Thomas yes indeed, I marked it as duplicate. Thanks